# how to get a div and its content from a php file using jquery and ajax?

Tags: jquery

how to get a div and its content from a php file using jquery and ajax?

For example,

php file

```
             echo "<div class='test1WrapperDiv'>";
                    echo "<div><p> Row 1 </p></div>";
                    echo "<div><p> Row 2 </p></div>";
                    echo "<div><p> Row 3 </p></div>";
                    echo "<div><p> Row 4 </p></div>";
              echo "</div>";

              echo "<div class='test2WrapperDiv'>";
                    echo "<div><p> Row 1 </p></div>";
                    echo "<div><p> Row 2 </p></div>";
                    echo "<div><p> Row 3 </p></div>";
                    echo "<div><p> Row 4 </p></div>";
              echo "</div>";
```

jquery code to get the returned data from an ajax call

```
                   $.post("test.php",{sendword: test1, table: table_name1}
                   function(data)
                   {
                       $("#Test1Section").append(data);
           });
```

What is the filter code to get only the test1WrapperDiv's class and its content from the php file?

Comment: @Cory: perhaps both divs are used, but at different places in the DOM?

Comment: @DavidHedlund: That makes... perfect sense. I should stay away from here on weekends, my brain isn't in coding mode :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$.post("test.php",{sendword: test1, table: table_name1}, function(data) {
    $(data).find('.test1WrapperDiv').appendTo('#Test1Section');
});
```

Comment: it does not work but if I put in the element name, it works, for example,  $(data).find('div').appendTo('#Test1Section');

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can supply CSS selector as a part of the url.

```
$("#Test1Section").load("test.php .test1WrapperDiv",{sendword: test1, table: table_name1});
```

Alternatively you can parse out the required stuff in the success handler

```
function(data) { $(data).find(".test1WrapperDiv").appendTo("#Test1Section");}
```